# Why do i need to set kwargs as parameter of CBV in Django

Tags: django, django-views

While overriding get_context_data,2 parameters are passed self and **kwargs while the CBV already has kwargs at 
`self.kwargs`(which are arguments passed from URL to the CBV)

Why do we need this extra kwargs(one passed to the function)

[Example of overriding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrHmN.png)

and even updating the context dict with function kwargs as shown in line 64.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `kwargs` in `get_context_data` and by itself has nothing to do with the attribute `self.kwargs` of the view.

It is just a naming convention to call the parameter that captures keyword argument `kwargs`.

My suggestion would be to look at the different Class Based Views provided by Django and the underlying Mixin to get a better understanding. The website [ccbv.co.uk](https://ccbv.co.uk) is very helpful for that.